# RewriteCond backrefrence to another RewriteCond causing 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have setup a *.mydomain.com subdomain in cpanel (cpanel, no shell access)
Going to anything.mydomain.com gets me to the same directory which I mounted for *.mydomain.com

So when I go to test.mydomain.com with the following in  .htaccess,

What works properly is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.+)\.(.+?\..+?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/(.+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /%1/$1
```

What doesn't work and gives a 500 Error is this (Just replaced the test with %1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.+)\.(.+?\..+?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/(.+)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /%1/$1
```

What I want to do is allow dynamic setup of subdomains if a subdirectory with it's name exists. The rewriting is done gracefully when I hardcode the subdomain name *test* in the .htaccess and not when I use a backrefrence *%1* for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a % variable or a backreference as part of the regular expression in a `RewriteCond`. You can create a string usimg a backreference and a # regex backreference:

```
 RewriteCond %1:%{REQUEST_URI} !^([^:]+):/\1/(.+)?$
```

So you create a string made up of the subdomain of the host match, a colon, then the URI, match against the subdomain in your regex, and reference it using \1.

Additionally, you may need to add another `%{HTTP_HOST}` match right after because the %1 backreference might have gotten reset because you can't backreference a *non* match.

Comment: It's working now and I didn't need to use another %{HTTP_HOST} most probably as nothing was matched, the previously captured %1 is still valid (Maybe it's just specific to my config. Would be nice to know if someone confirms it's universal). Thank you so much for this!

Comment: It also seems to me that the procedure used by me is not so secure and can be used by eavesdroppers. Can you suggest measures to be taken to counter any possible attacks (like accessing directories with a sub domain and publicizing it, when it can affect seo and also highlight other security issues.

Comment: @YashGupta I don't think there's anything you can do about that. It's no different than someone trying to request random directories.

Comment: Oh yes, I couldn't relate that earlier. Also, can the code support accessing something like test.mydomain.com/test/myfile.php, where it should rewrite the url to test.mydomain.com/test/test/myfile.php and not end in an infinite loop? Or Should I instruct my users to not to create a root directory with the same name as their subdomain?

Comment: @YashGupta well, you'd already have a /test/ directory because that's where everything is getting rewritten to. If the request was for `test.mydomain.com/test/myfile.php`, the condition above would fail and nothing would get rewritten.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. The condition would fail and rewriting is done. Is there anything we can do for it? Or is it a limitation of allowing dynamic sub domains this way?

Comment: @YashGupta You could add additional conditions to check if the requested resource exists using the `-f` and `-d` flags. Something along the lines of `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f`